# Trying to call a variable from JSON

Tags: angularjs

New to AngularJS so apologies if my terminology isn't correct. I am trying to call a value that is in my JSON body, however the difference is that it's also inside another body called student.

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "teacherName": "N/A",
  "students": [
    {
      "student": "n/a"
    }
  ],
  "status": "ALIVE"
}
```

My JS code consists of the following:

```
$scope.table = function () {
    SpringDataRestService.get(
        {
            collection: "school",
            resource: $scope.teacherSelected.id
        },
        function (response) {
            var students= [];
            for (var j = 0; j < response.students.length; j++) {
                var entitlement= {
                    student: response[j].student,
                };
                students.push(entitlement);
            }
            $log.info(JSON.stringify(entitlement))
            $scope.tableOptions = new NgTableParams({}, {
                dataset: students,
                counts: []
            });
        }
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in `for` loop. Instead of:

```
student: response[j].student
```

you need to use this:

```
student: response.students[j].student
```

Check this working demo: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4rnevLa5/13/)